# Can't see my email template

Tags: lightning, community, email, email-template

I have Classic email template, and its work when I test to send
but unfortunatelly I can't see this template if I try to use it from Record Page, like this following image
[image]

- I thought its because the template type is **Text**, I change it to **custom** template type but it's doesn't work
- I also already move it into a folder (because right now its under **Unfilled Public Classic Email Template**), but still doesn't work

Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache of your browser ?

Comment: Yes I already clear my browser cache. but not work